# path of running bash script found when re-runs as sudo

Tags: bash

The following code checks if you have root authority, then runs the script again with it :

```
    CMDLN_ARGS="$@" # Command line arguments for this script (if any)
    export CMDLN_ARGS
    func_check_for_sudo() {
        if [ ! $( id -u ) -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "You may be asked for your login password for [`whoami`]." ;sleep 1
                LAUNCH="`dirname \"${0}\"`"
                exec sudo -S su -c ${LAUNCH}/$(basename ${0}) ${CMDLN_ARGS}
        exit ${?}
    fi
    }
```

Where things are going wrong is when I place this script in a "$HOME/bin" folder or something so I can just launch it without the path.  It gives me the error "No such file or directory". I need the script to get that information and correctly pass it to exec.

My question is this: how do I get the /path/to/script_name from within a script correctly when it is called without the path? To recap, I'm calling MY_SCRIPT insead /path/to/MY_SCRIPT which breaks my script because it has to check for root authority and run again if you don't have it.

Basically the line of code in question is this where ${0} is the script name (with path if you called it with one):

```
    exec sudo -S su -c ${0} ${CMDLN_ARGS}
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to gain root privileges and then running `su` to gain root privileges a second time?  Why are you separating `$LAUNCH` at all (with an excruciatingly contorted line of code), instead of just running `exec sudo -S "$0" "$@"`? This might fail if the relevant directory from PATH is not on root's PATH, but that was going to happen anyway (if $LAUNCH is set to '.' because `$0` contains no path component).

Comment: Yeah I was just using LAUNCH to test things out but the reason for sudo is that the user will not know root per se..   Thank you for your comments. Appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

- Finding the path to the script. There are a couple of easy ways to do this: use `"$BASH_SOURCE"` instead of `$0`; or simply take advantage of the fact that (at least by default), sudo preserves $PATH, so `sudo "$0" ...` will resolve the script fine.
- The second is that the script doesn't preserve its arguments properly. Spaces within arguments will be mistaken for breaks between arguments, and wildcards will be erroneously expanded. This is because `CMDLN_ARGS="$@"` mushes all the arguments together separated by spaces, and then `${CMDLN_ARGS}` re-splits on spaces (maybe not the same way) and also expands wildcards.

Here's my take at correcting the problems. Note that putting the handler in a function just adds a layer of unnecessary complication, so I just put it inline. I also used sudo's -p option to clean up the prompting slightly.

```
if [ $( id -u ) -ne 0 ]; then
    exec sudo -p "Login password for %p: " "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi
```

Comment: thank you for responding and the thoughtful tips.  I'm still having an issue though, I see this:        `[itsupport@oc7626837528 ~]$ pwd
/home/itsupport
        [itsupport@oc7626837528 ~]$ which ironkey-helper.x`  Meaning that if I launch it by calling the command it fails .. 
        ~/bin/ironkey-helper.x
        [itsupport@oc7626837528 ~]$ ironkey-helper.x
        sudo: ironkey-helper.x: command not found

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not finding it, but try using `"$BASH_SOURCE"` instead of `"$0"` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I noticed the issue is when I compile the script using shc... your code works.

Comment: I can see how compiling the script would complicate matters. I haven't tested, but I'd expect that `"$BASH_SOURCE"` would work even when compiled -- it should find & run the decrypted script, rather than looking for the compiled wrapper.

Comment: What I did was run the script and I added a line that printed out the value for BASH_SOURCE, it works when I run it as a script but is blank when run with the wrapper.  I may need to export it or something. I like asking for root (sudo) up front but now it's really going to be a problem .. hmmm